# StringBuilder in Async Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5, async-await

If I fire off multiple async web requests, is it safe to append the result to a global variable, such as a `StringBuilder`?  I know the order is not guaranteed.

1. Does this cause a lot of Task blocking?
2. Is this safe?

```
private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private static async Task AccessTheWebAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(@"http://www.google.com/");
    sb.Append(response.StatusCode).Append(Environment.NewLine);        
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        tasks.Add(AccessTheWebAsync());
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this cause a lot of Task blocking?

No.  You will wait on all of the tasks to complete, but this is by design.  Otherwise, this is a fairly efficient way to write this.

> Is this safe?

This is not safe.  As documented in [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx): "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."  (In this case, `Append` is an instance method.)

Since you're running this in a console application, the Append calls will happen on separate threads.  You need some form of synchronization, such as using a `lock` statement around the `Append` call.

Note that, if you were to use this same code in a Windows Forms or WPF application, however, the code which runs after `await` would be scheduled using the initial `SynchronizationContext`, which would cause it to always run on the UI thread, so you wouldn't have thread synchronization issues.  Since it's in a console application, however, the continuations will run on separate threads.

Comment: [You could add a synchronization context to your console app, if you were so inclined](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3.aspx).

Comment: This is more-so a follow-up I guess.  Would it then be more logical perhaps to make the signature `private static async Task<string> AccessTheWebAsync()` returning the `response.StatusCode` and then finally, after the `WaitAll` loop through and append all the `Result`s?

Comment: @user17753 Yes, actually, that probably would be better.